# Can there be a two-neutron bound state?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons, strong-force

Is is possible for two neutrons to be in a bound state, assuming that they only interact gravitationally?

Comment: Various related (duplicate?) questions: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/242604/ http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202581/

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *assuming that they only interact gravitationally*? As the question Rob linked shows, a dineutron is not bound by the strong force, but I suppose in principle the neutrons could form a bound state due to the gravitational force. However the energy of this bound state would be so small that in practice it could never be formed.