# Why is diproton unstable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, particle-physics, strong-force

Diproton is an isotope of helium without any neutrons. It commonly forms in the Sun, where protons are fused constantly. However, it is extremely unstable, and will revert back to two protons almost immediately after.

Now, nucleons are held together by the strong interaction. So if the electromagnetic interaction is weaker than the strong interaction, why won't the protons stay held together instead of repelling one another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Why are the dineutron and diproton unbound?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147499/)

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/242700